# "TypeError: x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function" in phantom wallet...transfer sol to another account in JavaScript with@solana/web3.js

Tags: javascript, web3js

```js
let transaction = new solanalib.Transaction().add(
  solanalib.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    toPubkey: 'GJ7bZskjGFqph51T88W2E1A1TeT1YVuuFM8atQAtVhSz',
    lamports: solanalib.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  }),
);
transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;
if (transaction) {
  console.log('Txn created successfully');
} else {
  console.log('Sorry');
}

const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction);
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
console.log('Signature: ', signature);
```

Comment: Can you explain where you are stuck ? what is the issue ? Do you have logs ?

Comment: @Elikill58 yes sure i'll share my code wait a min

Answer (score 3):

I've just managed to solve this issue. The problem is that you are passing a string as the toPubKey - should be a PublicKey instance. Try this:

```
let transaction = new solanalib.Transaction().add(
  solanalib.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    toPubkey: new solanalib.PublicKey('GJ7bZskjGFqph51T88W2E1A1TeT1YVuuFM8atQAtVhSz'),
    lamports: solanalib.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  })
);
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind introducing me to this solanalib? I would like to generate PublicKey instance from base58 pubkey string. Is it part of solana/web3.js?

Comment: @ShintaroTakechi  yes